# Как обработать json ответа?

Tags: php, curl

Делаю запрос

```
 curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACa83850ffd33d1d2752798ea7576e1f/Messages.json' -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'To=+79525442020' \
--data-urlencode 'From=+12242190311' \
--data-urlencode 'Body=Hello world!' \
-u ACa83850ffd7305d1d2752798ea7576e1f:224e7d8233436663abc1b5d26238a

$response = curl_exec($ch);
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
```

Ответ

```
{
    "sid": "SM413c7bfb3ее94a5db4bdce7ea5c2a0a6",
    "date_created": "Sat, 10 Mar 2018 17:09:58 +0000",
    "date_updated": "Sat, 10 Mar 2018 17:09:58 +0000",
}
```

Как правильно обратать такой ответ?

Comment: Что значит обработать? Вот Вы получили ответ, у вас есть массив response, что вы еще хотите?

Comment: поменяйте ключи на учетке вашей. тут в тексте спалили код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
$response['date_created'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s O', $response['date_created']);
$response['date_updated'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s O', $response['date_updated']);
var_dump($response);
```